# iOS MapKit - How do I center the map on a specific location I get from text fields in a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

iOS MapKit - How do I center the map on a specific location I get from text fields in a view?

It seems there are droves of tutorials on how to centre the map on the user's current location. How do I centre on a location I input manually?

Comment: Are you adding a pin ? I know If you call mapView.showAnnotations, and input the one item in the array the map should zoom into that annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example in Objective-C on how to center your Map whenever the location of the user has been updated:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

So, if you need to center your map/screen on a specific location, just copy the code inside this delegate method, and change the coordinate.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example (in `swift`) I used recently, where I have a variable `location` - which you can create from your textfields, and you will also need to define height and width of the zoomed area

```
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation, regionRadius : CLLocationDistance)
{
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
        latitudinalMeters, longitudinalMeters)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

In my example, the user has a configurable option to re-open the map at the last known position, or on the current location.